# Red Gate Oracle Schema Compare v3 to v4 doesn't interpret UserObjectPrivileges

Tags: sql, oracle, compare, redgate

I am using Red Gate Oracle Schema Compare version 3 to generate migration scripts for our database.

However in going to version 4, the schema comparison with Scripts folder does not successfully interpret UserObjectPrivileges.  It generates REVOKES.

How can I resolve this issue?

This might be related, but Red Gate Oracle Schema Compare version 4 also detects "objects that exist in both but are different" between the files exported to the filesystem by version 3 and the files exported to the filesystem by version 4 even though I've compared them in Notepad++ and using the command line fc /b (binary compare) and no differences are detected. I even copied and pasted one over the other, but they still are seen as "objects that exist in both but are different".

Comment: Not something I use.  But from a Q&A standpoint, this question seems to need a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Can you make the error happen on a tiny database with a single table, with few enough commands to create the situation to post in your question?  Can you show the output from v3, then the output from v4?  Then if you make a tiny example and don't get a problem, it could be something unusual about your database...

Comment: Many thanks HostileFork. It's not easy to create a database in a hurry in our environment as Medical and the Oracle Server is heavily locked down, but will consider this as an option. I have raised a ticket with Red Gate, but as I mostly use StackOverflow as a technical reference with C#, SQL and Javascript and so thought worth asking the question (couldn't find anything on StackOverflow about this topic). So please don't downvote in a hurry - a minimal verifiable example is on the way but will be slow to arrive.

Comment: Questions on C# or JavaScript are a rather different category of questions on RedGate product support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I asked Red Gate support and the response is as follows:

"It looks like these are intended changes. The differences you are seeing are caused by changes we have made in saving grants to the files (released in version 3.0.16). In this case it is not a bug - this is the intended action, because files now have to be rebuilt. If you wants to equal this you should deploy with these grants. After the first deploy, you should then change the comparison site and deploy again (if it shows any differences in grants again). After this actions object privileges should be compatible with the latest Schema Compare version."